# Points where this function is continuous: $f(z) = 3/z$ for $z=\pm 1$, and $(z^3-1)/(z^2-1)$ otherwise

Tags: complex-analysis

> In what points is this function continuous?
>   $$f(z)= \begin{cases}
>              \dfrac{3}{z} &\text{if}\;z=\pm 1 \\[6pt]
>              \dfrac{z^3-1}{z^2-1} &\text{if}\;z\not=\pm 1\\
>              \end{cases}$$

**My attempt:**

I think i need verify if $f$ satisfies Cauchy-Riemann equations, in other words: $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$

And see if the partial derivatives of $u,v$ are continuous.

But i'm stuck. Can someone help me?

Comment: Cauchy-Riemann equations must be satisfied to be complex *differentiable*

Comment: @J.W.Tanner but if the function is differentiable then is continous in that point.

Comment: Yes...but not the other way around.

Comment: as $z\to1$, $\dfrac{z^3-1}{z^2-1}=\dfrac{z^2+z+1}{z+1}\to\dfrac32$

Answer (score 2):

You just need to go back to the very friendly continuity criterion check that $\lim_{z\rightarrow 1}f(z)=f(1)$, $\lim_{z\rightarrow -1}f(z)=f(-1)$ are true or not.

In the later case, the limit even blows up. The discontinuities are $z=1,-1$.

Comment: In this case $\lim_{z\rightarrow 1}f(z)=\lim_{z\rightarrow 1}\dfrac{z^3-1}{z^2-1}$ or i need consider  $\lim_{z\rightarrow 1}\dfrac{3}{z}$ ?

Comment: The former one, because we are looking at the neighborhood of $1$.

Comment: Great, thanks for all